# undefined reference error CUDA, GPUJPEG Library

Tags: linker, cuda, shared-libraries

I have successfully installed this library. My code compiles without issue but I'm getting this error, which I believe is during linking:

```
suvamsh@vai:~/gpujpeg-lib/src$ nvcc test.cu
/tmp/tmpxft_00002869_00000000-13_test.o: In function 'encoder()':
tmpxft_00002869_00000000-1_test.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x23d): undefined reference to `gpujpeg_set_default_parameters(gpujpeg_parameters*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have even set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to location of the library .so file. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will have to explicitly specify the library to the compiler and supply the path where you installed it, if it is in a "non-standard" place. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only effects runtime behaviour, not linking or compiling behaviour.

Comment: @talonmies How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @talonmies,

> You will have to explicitly specify the library to the compiler and supply the path where you installed it, if it is in a "non-standard" place.

Try the following command

```
$ nvcc test.cu -o test -L"path/to/GPUJPEGLibrary" -l"name_of_GPUJPEGLibrary"
```

Note that if the name of the .so file is libxyz.so, the "name_of_GPUJPEGLibrary" should be "xyz".

For example, if your .so file is /usr/local/lib/libgpujpeg.so, the cmdline should be

```
$ nvcc test.cu -o test -L"/usr/local/lib" -l"gpujpeg"
```

Comment: I tried the above command but I'm still encountering the same error.

#include <libgpujpeg/gpujpeg.h>
#include <libgpujpeg/gpujpeg_util.h>
That's how I have included the header files.

Comment: The error msg suggest you don't have problem in including the header files in your source code. "path/to/GPUJPEGLibrary" should be the location of .so file, not of the header files. for example, if your .so file is /usr/local/lib/libgpujpeg.so, the cmdline should be `$ nvcc test.cu -o test -L"/usr/local/lib" -l"gpujpeg"`

Comment: The path "/usr/local/lib" contains the .so file. Yet I'm getting the same error.
Could there be another reason for getting this error?

Comment: then try -L"/usr/local/lib64" if you use x86_64 system